# Duda con la sintaxis en CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estoy siguiendo este tutorial de codigofacilito en Youtube:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tJI2buWwrjE&list=PLuaU46Q2O0VojYJHvEahzGgtSIwz9uUD4&index=10

Trato de hacer el formulario, pero no me aparece en pantalla, y es por el hecho de que en el video usan una sintaxis muy distinta a la de php, la cual copio pero no funciona en mi xampp.

Por ejemplo, en el video hacen esto:

```
<?= form_input($nombre) ?>
```

Pero si lo hago así, no me funciona, por lo que me veo obligado a usar la forma "a la antigua" de php, así:

```
<?php echo form_input($nombre) ?>
```

Así sí me funciona.

Por ahí oí algo sobre que debo cambiar algo en php.ini para poder usar esa sintaxis resumida. La verdad es que no soy fan de esa sintaxis resumida y prefiero la de php, pero quiero poder seguir los ejemplos de los videos al pie de la letra o me perderé.

¿Cómo activo esos comandos resumidos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esa caracteristica tienes que habilitarla en tu archivo php.ini, especificamente modificando

```
short_open_tag
```

Para eso busca tu archivo php.ini y abrelo en un editor de texto, busca la linea short_open_tag, si esta comentada descomentala y cambiala por:

```
short_open_tag = On
```

Luego reinicia tu servidor.

> Nota: Esta directiva también afecta a la abreviatura `<?=` en versiones
>   anteriores a PHP 5.4.0, la cual es lo mismo que `<? echo`. El uso de
>   esta abreviatura requería que short_open_tag estuviese activada. Desde
>   PHP 5.4.0, `<?=` siempre está disponible.

Mas información en:

https://secure.php.net/manual/es/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Comment: Gracias, era tal cual eso.